# grid panel error tooltip

Tags: css, extjs, extjs4, tooltip

I have a gridpanel and want to show a errortooltip on mouse hover as we see for textfields and combobox. Is there any inbuilt component to show this error styled tooltip for grid panel.
[image: this is how i am expecting my toolip on mouse hover on grid panel]

i am doing this to find validate based on the number of records in the grid panel.Please Help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing built-in to accomplish this, but you can still do it. Lucky for you, I had to do something like this not too long ago.

You'll need to use a column renderer. You'll also need to store the error message on the record itself, or have a way to access error messages by record. Your renderer should look something like this:

```
renderer: function(value, metaData, record){
    if(/* record has error */){
        metaData.tdCls += " x-form-invalid-field";  // Squiggly red lines
        metaData.tdAttr = "data-errorqtip='This is my error message!'";
    }
    return value;
}
```

You may need to play around with styling and whatnot, but that is the gist of it. Also, you'll have to refresh your grid if the validity of your records changes, to make sure your tooltips say updated.